# Trouble with improper integral convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

How do I quickly spot that
$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(1-x^3)}}$ is convergent? I am really lost at figuring these problems out and need som help understanding the way of thinking. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickly! Use the asymptotic comparison:

$$\frac1{\sqrt{x(1-x^3)}}\sim_0 \frac1{\sqrt x}$$
and the integral
$$\int_0^{1/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}$$
is convergent. Moreover,
$$\frac1{\sqrt{x(1-x^3)}}\sim_1\frac1{\sqrt3\sqrt{1-x}}$$
and the integral
$$\int_{1/2}^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt {1-x}}$$
is also convergent. Conclude.